# What does eval do with FD redirects?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there any difference, logically or semantically, between the following?

```
$ eval 'echo hello >/dev/null'
$ eval "echo hello" >/dev/null
```

More generally: does the shell ever redirect the output `eval` itself? Or is `eval` always given the redirect as an argument (to then pass back to the shell)?

And does this behavior depend on the type of shell (sh/bash/zsh/etc)?

Comment: In the second case, the shell is redirecting the output of eval.

Comment: BTW, `sh`, `bash`, `dash`, `ksh` and kin are all in the same family (of shells that at least claim to support a superset of POSIX-standardized syntax); `zsh` is intentionally *not* part of that family, and doesn't offer any guarantees of compatibility with the others listed (except when placed in a mode specific to that purpose, as by starting it under the `sh` name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all POSIX-compliant shells, `eval` is treated exactly like every other command at the syntax-parsing layer -- it receives a list of individual arguments (after quote-removal and other processing stages common to all commands), and only after being invoked concatenates them together into a single string to be evaluated. <sup>[1]</sup>

Similarly, like every other command, redirections specified as shell syntax (a description which applies to `>/dev/null` but not `">/dev/null"`) are applied before the command itself is executed.

This means that in the `eval "echo hello" >/dev/null` case, the `>/dev/null` redirection happens *before* `eval` is executed.

By contrast, `eval 'echo hello >/dev/null'` runs the redirection from within `eval`, before the `echo`.

---

<sup>[1] - (This is the cause of many bugs in end-user code: People who expect (broken) `eval printf '%s\n' $args` to be the same as (working) `eval "printf '%s\n' $args"` are often quite surprised; if testing those two, consider `args='"first word" "second word"'` as a simple case).</sup>